# Symfony2 User Provider from RESTful webservice

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create a simple User Provider in Symfony 2, but i have no idea how this is supposed to work with a webservice. Authentication in my company is handled by a RESTful webservice, with various routes:

```
POST /user, GET /user, POST /login
```

So, when creating a Symfony 2 app, my user provider must consult the web service in order to verify credentials and permissions. Is this possible? Is there a bundle for something like this?

Also, how can i achieve a good performance on this? The way the Symfony user provider works, i guess it will consult the web service on EACH request, in order to get the user data. Can this be avoided?

Answer (score -1):

There are two great bundles you can use:

For dealing REST reqs try FOSRestBundle (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle),
And for User Provider try FOSUserBundle (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle)

Those are good bundles, and you can get good documentation, too.

Comment: This is not what i'm looking for, please, read the question once again.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this by implementing an authentication provider and user provider, each will handle the call to your web service for auth. 
You could have a client class to make the web service calls, and cache the response somewhere to avoid having it called every request, although the need for that depends on how slow the web service is.

I have done this approach so can fill in the gaps if you need.

Comment: I did that, my question is: how can i avoid the common pitfalls, such as having a terrible performance due to request saturation? As i said earlier, i'm worried about the fact the Symfony keeps calling the webservice (through the UserProvider) on every request.

Comment: And as I said, implement response caching in your api client. Cache to redis, memcache, or something else. And pretty sure you didn't say you had done it that way so doesn't deserve a minus 1